# Simpler syntax for IDisposable than using block?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I wrote this code

```
var doc = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

But then I remembered one should use C#'s using block to make sure the StreamReader's clean-up method Dispose is called as soon as possible. That gave me this code

```
string doc;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

That's longer and harder to read. Is there a simpler one line syntax that still does the IDisposable stuff correctly?

Comment: "Give them an inch..." :-) Syntactic sugar for the syntactic sugar? There is none.

Comment: Use using and don't invent bicycle.

Comment: How much shorter do you want it? That's already pretty short...

Answer (score 2):

With only one line inside the block you can simply write

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

However there is no way to simplify this any further. `using` is just some syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

try
{
    doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
finally
{
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

And this doesn't even prevent you from accessing the object after it has been disposed. So `using` is actually the short way to get the job done.

One note on combining `using`-statements: If you are working with `FileStream` and `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`, you can simply combine many `using`-statements to one:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the dispose method manually like this:

```
var reader= new StreamReader(stream);

try
{
    var doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
finally
{
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Which is in fact equivalent to the using syntax. But the using is still the shortest way to write it.

Comment: This is missing the whole point of `using`, which is: exceptions may get thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the exceptions. This is totally correct. I edited my answer.

Comment: using statement is equivalent to a try/finally statement

Answer (score 0):

No. 3 operations generally require 3 lines.. especially if each operation returns something.

You have a couple of options:

1. All on one line.
2. Explicitly calling `Dispose()`.
3. `using`.. like it was intended :)

If extra lines is what you're worried about.. you're worrying about the wrong things.